# Changing the border colour of 4 circles one after the other?

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I have 4 rings of circles that are white and I want one of them to change blue for 1 second, the next one for one second, and so on, totalling 4 seconds. I was thinking of trying this with just CSS animations but I think I'll need JavaScript.. any ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks!

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYFXV.jpg

HTML:

```
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
          <div class="circle c4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.c2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-color: white;
}

.c3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: white;
}

.c4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ydb48372/3/

Comment: No need for js, you can do all you need to with css animations. If you want to step the animations you can use `animation-delay`. Try something with CSS animations, so we can see what you've attempted rather than write it all for you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with just `css` animations. First create animation of 4s duration that sets border-color to blue for 1s or `25%` of time of those 4 seconds and the rest of animation returns border-color to gray or `75%` of full animation time. Now you just need to use `animation-delay` on each circle so that animation on one circle starts after 1s when color from previous circle has changed to gray.

```css
.circles {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-name: changeColor;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.c1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
}
.c2 {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
.c3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.c4 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

@keyframes changeColor {
  0% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  24% {
    border-color: #1C50A8;
  }
  25% {
    border-color: gray;
  }
  100% {
    border-color: gray;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
        <div class="circle c4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: @ovokuro Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use css3 key frames to achieve what you are looking for. You might have to play with the numbers to get the exact timings you want but it should be achievable.

```
div {
    -webkit-animation: mymove 5s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0%   {border-color: white;}
    100% {border-color: blue;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {border-color: white;}
    100% {border-color: blue;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using animation-delay like a commentator mentions is correct.

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 max-width: 100%;
}

.c2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-color: white;
}

.c3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: white;
}

.c4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.c1, .c2, .c3, .c4 {
  animation: 400ms change-border-color forwards;
}
.c2 {
  animation-delay: 450ms;
}
.c3 {
  animation-delay: 900ms;
}
.c4 {
  animation-delay: 1350ms;
}
@keyframes change-border-color {
  from { border-color: white; }
  to { border-color: blue; }
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
    <div class="circle c4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Refer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations) **animation** and **animation-delay** property in css

```
 animation: animate 1s;
 animation-delay: 1s;
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4mjwfsp/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a pseudoelement on `.circles`

I've used keyframes to change the `height`, `width` and `position`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/6L2rbfbd/)

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.circles {
  position: relative;
}

.circles::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: 10px solid blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-animation: blue 5s infinite;
  -moz-animation: blue 5s infinite;
  -o-animation: blue 5s infinite;
  animation: blue 5s infinite;
}

.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
  border: 10px solid white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.c2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-color: white;
}

.c3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: white;
}

.c4 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

@keyframes blue {
  25% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    top: 0px;
  }
  25.001% {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  50% {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    top: 25px;
  }
  50.001% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  75% {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50px;
  }
  75.001% {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 75px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    top: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circles">
  <div class="circle c1">
    <div class="circle c2">
      <div class="circle c3">
        <div class="circle c4"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```